# Xamarin XAML with Reshaper's Intellisense

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, resharper, intellisense

I'm using VS 2015 with Resharper Ultimate 2017.1.2 installed
The thing is the Reshaper's Intellisense doesn't recognize the XAML objects from code behind which forbids me from looking inside the object's members, the code compiles and runs just fine for all platforms it's just I can't use the Intellisense which lowers the productivity

Comment: It had worked fine for me most of the time in the past (I have since moved on to VS 2017). One thing you must do in later versions is to save the XAML file after making a change for it to be accessible from your code-behind. Even then though, R# would mess up. Usually closing Visual Studio and/or deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders would help. You could also try clearing the R# solution cache in R# General Settings menu.

Comment: Have you tried clearing resharper's caches?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with disabling Resharper.

> Visual Studio > Tools | Options | ReSharper | General : Suspend

**Update:**
*When I install the latest ReSharper version (2017.2), the problem is solved.*